# No protocol method defined for type object: :empty

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I'm trying to fix a bug in a Clojurescript frontend using Reagent and Re-frame. I find the error messages a little difficult to decipher at times and I can't crack this one.

All I know is that I'm getting a bug in a particular view like this:

`No protocol method IAssociative.-assoc defined for type object: :empty`

I'm going to take a wild guess that I'm trying to assoc something with the type `:empty`. What kind of data would have a type of `:empty`?

Am I at least on the right track? What sorts of things could raise an exception like this?

This is what my stack trace looks like:

[image]

Comment: If you have an exception, you should also have a stacktrace, which then leads you to the code you control (where it is happending).  Then debug from there?

Comment: That's typically what I'd do, but I can't seem to replicate the bug, and my bug tracking service hasn't really left me with a valuable stack trace.

Comment: You will have an easier time to find your problem once you get a stacktrace, that relates to the code (e.g. use source maps)

Comment: My guess is that an object `x` of type `:empty` is the *destination* of the `assoc`.

Comment: Function names "NAa", "KAa", "Mc", etc smell like "advanced" optimizations from Google Closure, an optional ClojureScript compilation step.  Sometimes, when you don't know what's going on, it helps to change optimization to "none".  Then the problem might go away (suggesting an incompatibility with Google Closure) or the problem might get clearer.

Comment: As @AlanThompson said, my bet would be that somewhere somehow you've got `(assoc :empty something)`. What the error message is telling you is that to keyword `:empty` doesn't implement the `IAssociative` protocol (because of course it doesn't). If you can't track it down locally one trick you could try is actually implementing that protocol and throwing a custom exception with more details about your app. Or put out a build with `:pseudo-names true` (https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#pseudo-names) to some users experiencing the problem to try to get a better stack trace.